# Failed to generate a proxy class for Exchange EWS: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, keytool, wsimport, truststore

I want to generate a proxy class for EWS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx).

```
keytool -keystore t:\my.keystore -storepass password -import -trustcacerts -alias MY-CA -file t:\MY-CA.crt
keytool -keystore t:\my.keystore -storepass password -list
set VMARGS=-Djavax.net.debug=all
set VMARGS=%VMARGS% -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=t:\my.keystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
wsimport https://mail.xxxx.co.jp/ews/Exchange.asmx
```

But I get this error message:

```
[ERROR]
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wsimport -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=t:\my.keystore https://mail.xxxx.co.jp/ews/Exchange.asmx
```

It would appear that VMARGS is not being picked up by wsimport.

If the above works then proof conclusive.  Otherwise the issue is either you have the wrong RootCA added to your keystore or the keystore is not being read

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this is still an problem for JDK1.6.0u29

When running the following command:

```
wsimport -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:\jdk160_29\.mykeystore https://url.com?wsdl -p com.test -s ./src
```

I got the following error:

```
unrecognized parameter -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:\jdk160_29\.mykeystore
```

But I found a workaround to execute the following command:

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:\jdk160_29\.mykeystore -classpath C:\jdk160_29\lib\tools.jar com.sun.tools.internal.ws.WsImport https://ur.com?wsdl -p com.test -s ./src
```